# Center div horizontally and vertically with container of 100% width and height

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to center div in the middle of another element?

I have an container with with set to 100% and height to 130% of the screen but i fail to centr it int the middle ( of the container ).
i tried using

```
div {
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But this will just set the the content of div in the middle horizontally only , and set the width and height of the inner element to container element.

What is the best trick to achieve such thing? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/7npsfx3c/4/) is demo

Comment: that post does not help..

Comment: @trolkura If you do not post a working example we cannot know more about your code.

Comment: added demo to the question

Comment: Look at this [example](http://codepen.io/tom-maton/pen/oqsEJ) in one of the answers of the question marked as duplicate.